# How can I take a screenshot of my app running on a Samsung Smart TV?

Tags: screenshot, television

Is there any way to take a screenshot of my app running on a Samsung Smart TV 2014? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this is not a programming question.  Stack overflow is for programming questions only.

Comment: I guess it is. I have DEVELOPED an app for Samsung Smart TV and I need to take the screenshot of my own app that I need it in the submission process.

Comment: @La-comadreja I guess it would be polite to take your down-vote to my question back or give some reason for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 take out your smart phone/ camera 
2 take a pic of your TV screen

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering if there is any tools for that like Roku.

Comment: I was actually kidding :)

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question. Hope it will help somebody: 
Based on my research, there is not such a thing. You need to use the emulator to take screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Press Home and Power buttons together on your TV to take screenshots ;)

Comment: How will this get saved in your desktop/laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same situation.
I like the emulator idea, but another one is if you are able to run your app in a browser, you can run the browser full screen and take screen shots.